# How to show JSP page in Modal Popup window?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I am pretty much new to Jsp stuff. What I am trying to achieve is to show contents of another jsp page lets say help.jsp in service.jsp page but only when user click ? image (? image represents help). I want to show the contents of help.jsp in a popup window and also at the same time want the main screen to fade out or non intractable.

Here is what I am doing so far. I have created a div in service.jsp

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">

</div>
```

and created a javascript function

```
function openDialog() {
        $("#dialog").load('/myaccount/registration/help.jsp').dialog({modal: true});
    }
```

My anchor tag looks like this

```
 <a tabindex="1005" href="#"  onclick="openDialog();" onMouseOver="window.status='Launch Help Window'; return true" onMouseOut ="window.status='';return true"><span class="WhiteBody"><img src="images/icon_help.gif" border="0"></span></a>
```

When I click help button it redirect to a blank page.

Please help me !

Comment: Instead try include `<jsp:include page="help.jsp" /> ` inside div tag and hide it. Show that when button click.

Comment: Can you please explain with code snippets ?  Actually I tried include tag but it always shows on the main page. Tried hiding it with different ways but in vain.

Comment: Check my answer and let know

Answer (score 5):

In your HTML,

```
<button id="myButton">click!</button>

<div id="dialog" title="Dialog box">
  My content // Have to add your jsp page here
</div>
```

And in your Script,

```
$(function() {

  $("#dialog").dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true
   });

  $("#myButton").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });

});
```

See the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvZc4/1108/)** for working sample.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The problem is when I display jsp page in div using '<jsp:include page="help.jsp" />' it shows the contents of JSP on the main page.

Comment: Is it displaying the unprocessed HTML?